# grails 3.3.x java.sql.Date property is type-mismatched

Tags: date, grails

In my domain class, I have something like this:

```
class User {
  String name
  java.sql.Date birthDate
}
```

I am getting the app working with scaffolding, and the scaffolded creation pages correctly show the d/m/y drop down date picker to specify the date, which is very good.

But when I hit the "Create" button, it gives:

> Property birthDate is type-mismatched"

I am using the built in H2 DB currently, but will switch to MySQL later.

Any suggestions?  I don't want to use the normal date/time as I only need the date, and it must not be affected by time zones. Obviously I could manually store the day, month and year fields separately, but this makes it harder to use later (e.g. for comparison).

We had a trick to get this working with Grails 2.x, but I don't have a copy of this old code.

Does anyone have a workaround for getting this working with the fields plugins?

In my update controller method, even if I manually set `user.birthDate` to a correct `java.sql.Date` instance, calling `user.save()` still fails with the type-missmatch error.  It seems to be something in the `save()` method, which is presumably GORM code.

Comment: quick guess?  Use java.util.Date instead (or just Date, since I think you get that free in Groovy).  I'm pretty sure Grails handles the conversion to sql.Date during all the Hibernate stuff.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Note, we are specifically using java.sqlDate, and not Date or java.util.Date, becase the latter both have time as well as dates (i.e. they are timestamps with timezones).  We dont want timezones, as birthdates are always just dmy, not dmy hms zz etc.

Comment: Why don't you use java.time.LocalDate instead if you need only dmy ?

Comment: Sadly, grails doesnt support java.time.LocalDate.  It does display it, but it has no input/edit method.